# Error :Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<ProductListActivity>) is undefined

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and use **Gridview** to display 16 Text View Controls 
When user clicks a particular Text View control I need to open another activity
My **Gridview** item click event as follows

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductListActivity.class);
          } });
```

But this makes an error and says “The constructor 
`Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<ProductListActivity>)` is undefined”

Could someone please help me to correct this ?

Comment: your not passing the correct arguments to the intent constructor..
probably should look something like this given that you are doing this from an activity..

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProductListActivity.class);

Comment: @kamal: you should accept an answer or clarify, why you are unsatisfied with all of them. or people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Thank you, It works now.   How can I accept the answer ? putting some comments ?  I am new to the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be:

```
       gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(activity_name.this, ProductListActivity.class);
      } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the context as first argument. In your case `YourActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      switch (position)
{
case 1:
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, ProductListActivity.class);
break;
case 2:
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
break;   
default: // default.....
break;
}});
```

Handle your activities with switch case....

Answer (score 0):

send getApplicationContext or yourActivity.this as the first parameter in your intent. Hope this solve your issue.